# Ejabberd 16.09 Mod_Rest installation

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm using ejabberd 16.09 and I've tried to make a fresh install today.(download the deb package from ejabberd.im website)
Then I 've executed the following commands to install mod_rest

```
ejabberdctl modules_update_specs
ejabberdctl module_install mod_rest
```

However it gave an error like this:

```
src/mod_rest.erl:40: can't find include file "xmpp.hrl"
```

I wasnt getting this error before, I dont know what has changed?

Comment: This also happens in 16.01. will let you what I come up with.

Comment: I can only find a solution with copying the old mod_rest folder from my already running jabbed 16.09 server to new server. Then run the module_install mod_rest command. If someone else knows a better way I would be glad

Comment: we switched to a push approach for our use case: availability: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/pull/207